# Separable $L_1$-predual

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Some isometric preduals of $\ell_1$ are of the form $C_0(K)$ where $K$ is countable. I am wondering whether this is a general rule.

Question: Is there a measure $\mu$ and a (preferably **separable**) Banach space $X$ without a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$ which has $X^*=L_1(\mu)$ isometrically?

I apologise for three questions in a such short period of time. Now I'll take my time.

EDIT: Corrected according to Philip's remarks.

Comment: The first sentence of your post is incorrect; what *is* true is that when $C_0(K)^\ast$ is isometric to $\ell_1$ it is necessarily the case that $K$ is countable. There are isometric preduals of $\ell_1$ that are not isomorphic to a space $C_0(K)$; the first example is due to Benyamini and Lindenstrauss, *A predual of $\ell_1$ which is not isomorphic to a $C(K)$ space*, Israel J. Math. **13** (1972), 246-254. Other constructions have since been given, see Gasparis' preprint http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4317.pdf for a brief survey. Gasparis' paper contains a new approach to constructing an $\ell_$

Comment: isometric predual of $\ell_1$. The difference between his space and earlier constructions is that his space does not contain a subspace isomorphic to $C_0([0,\omega^\omega])$. You can see a video of him presenting a talk on his paper at http://www.birs.ca/events/2012/5-day-workshops/12w5019/videos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zippin proved that every isometric $L_1$ predual contains $c_0$ isometrically.

Zippin, M.
On some subspaces of Banach spaces whose duals are L1 spaces. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 23 1969 378–385.

Comment: Is anything known about containment of $c$ isometrically?

Comment: @Jan: $c$ does not embed isometrically into $c_0$.